# What is DataWarehouseSyncBaseline in RTC?

Tags: rtc, baseline

This can be a basic question but I need to more information about this. I tried to search about this but I could not get about this. Can you please give more information.

Questions:
1. What is **DataWarehouseSyncBaseline** and its purpose?
2. What are the conditions/situations it is created?
3. Is there an option to stop the creation this baseline(DataWarehouseSyncBaseline)?

A little back ground why had the above questions:
Initially baseline with name **DataWarehouseSyncBaseline** was not created for our components by system automatically. Previously the **Data collection jobs** in **Reports** section where not running. As these reports where not running correctly, we are unable to get the data for the BIRT reports which are created by us. So in this regard, we made some changes for the data collection jobs settings in reports section(i.e., changed the user id and password - gave a valid useID and password). After making these changes, then the system started creating a new baseline for the components by name **DataWarehouseSyncBaseline automatically** every night if there are changes for that component from the previous day.

Thanks and Regards,
Vijay.

Comment: This is a duplicate of jazz.net forum question: https://jazz.net/forum/questions/161978/what-is-datawarehousesyncbaseline-in-rtc.

I believe that this topic should be closed.

Comment: That post was also posted by me only. After posting the question in Jazz.net, I didn't get any answer till then. So I thought to pose the same question here so that the question can be viewed by more people by which I can get an answer for this question.

Comment: Hi Vijay,From my experience jazz.net forum is more responsive than stackoverflow. If you need an answer on your question, please contact IBM support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it is working as expected. During data collection job for SCM snapshot, if the baseline has been changed, it will create this "DataWarehouseSyncBaseline", the baseline will remains on component level. So no issue here

Please find the details below.

"The behavior is as expected. The ETL creates SCM snapshots which in turn create baselines. Then it deletes the snapshots when it does not need them. Deleting a snapshot does not delete the child baselines. So the baselines will stay. But they are not created against the stream. They get created against an ETL owned workspace. So 
no issue here. 
1,2) During data collection job for SCM snapshot it will creates on the component level.
3) You can try not select the streams for SCM ETL's

Note: This is one of the reasons we do not enable the SCM ETL on all streams. It is quite expensive and should only be enabled against the integration streams."

refernce: https://jazz.net/forum/questions/161978/what-is-datawarehousesyncbaseline-in-rtc